# ¿Cómo saber si se ha hecho clic en un menú?

Tags: windows, rust

Estoy usando el crate `winsafe` y quiero saber cuando se ha hecho clic en un menú.

`flags & MF_MOUSESELECT as u16` debería ser `1` cuando sí y `0` cuando no, pero siempre es `32768`.

¿Por qué?

```
self.wnd.on().wm(winsafe::co::WM::MENUSELECT, {
  move |params| {
    let wparam = params.wparam;
    let lparam = params.lparam;
    let flags = (wparam >> 16 & 0xffff) as u16;
    let MF_MOUSESELECT = 0x00008000 as u32;
    
    println!("{}", flags & MF_MOUSESELECT as u16);
    // siempre 32768

    0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-menuselect, `WM_MENUSELECT` ([`winsafe::co::MF::MOUSESELECT`](https://docs.rs/winsafe/0.0.6/winsafe/co/struct.MF.html#associatedconstant.MOUSESELECT)) esta definido como `0x00008000L`, que es igual a `32768`.

Si por verdad necesitas `0` o `1`, se puede usar `(flags & MF_MENUSELECT) >> MF_MENUSELECT.trailing_zeros()` ([`trailing_zeros`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.trailing_zeros) significa "bits de cero al fin", y el `>>` quita el mismo numero de bits del valor del flag).

Si solo necesitas `false` o `true` para un condicional, se puede usar `flags & MF_MENUSELECT != 0`.